# Import asset from CDN into Gatsby on page build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, gatsby

I want to import an asset (video) from a CDN (AWS CloudFront) into a specific page in Gatsby. I don't know how to do this.

I've tried adding an `import` statement at the top of the page that references the link to the asset, i.e: http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4. When I do and run `gatsby develop`, I get `This dependency was not found` and the link is referenced.

When I run `gatsby build`, I get the following error:

> Error: ./src/pages/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4' in 'C:\Users\David\Documents\wa mp\www\greystone\src\pages' resolve 'http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4' in 'C:\Users\David\Documents\wamp\www\greystone\src\pages' Parsed request is a module using description file: C:\Users\David\Documents\wamp\www\greystone\package.json (relative path: ./src/pages) Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration resolve as module C:\Users\David\Documents\wamp\www\greystone\src\pages\node_modules doesn 't exist or is not a directory

So Gatsby is trying to decipher the import as a module, it appears.

I found this page in the Gatsby Docs, [Importing Assets Directly Into Files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/), but there is no mention on how to do this using a CDN.

The import link on its own, when placed into the browser address bar works, but Gatsby fails to build/compile when trying to import the asset into the page this way.

```
import myVideo from 'http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4'

export default (props) => (
    ...
    <video src={myVideo}></video>
    ...
)
```

I expect the URL to be transpiled/compiled into the static HTML.

Comment: The message `Can't resolve 'http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4'` doesn't actually contain the string `[refId]`, does it?

Comment: No, I replaced the hash with that.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use the url directly in your component:

```
export default (props) => (
    ...
    <video src="http://[refId].cloudfront.net/myVideo.mp4"></video>
    ...
)
```

If you'd like to store the video & serve it with Gatsby, check out the helper function [`createRemoteFileNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/#createremotefilenode) from `gatsby-source-filesystem`.